# LLSD101A diode replacement

Tags: mosfet, diodes, dc-motor, h-bridge, motor-controller

I am ordering parts to build an [OSMC Motor Controller](http://www.robotpower.com/downloads/osmc3-22sch-clean.pdf) for a 24V system.

The schematics calls for [LLSD101A](https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/59096/DIODES/LLSD101A/182/1/LLSD101A.html) , surface mount Schottky barrier diode.
I would like to use through hole components, but I cannot find an equivalent diode, mainly because I am not sure what parameters are relevant. If somebody could come up with a suggestion it would be greatly appreciated.

Also I am planning to use only one mosfet per side, as the Motor requirements are not huge ( 24V motor, 20 Amps max). Should I reconsider the value of the gate resistor in light of this, and what wattage rating should these be?

thank you

Comment: 2pF 1ns for diode. And is 20A steady state or startup surge?

Comment: is SD101A-TAP a suitable replacement? 20A is maximum as the salvaged motor has a 20A fuse and my multimeter is only rated for 20A

Comment: Also I am having trouble finding the 2474-31L inductor. Can I use any 330uH 740mA inductor?

Comment: It should also have same DCR

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, DCR?

Comment: R at DC in all the datasheets

Comment: thanks, got it now. the only one I can find is RLB0914-331KL, the DCR is slightly different at 760 mOhm Vs 650 mOhm. Is it suitable?